# VB.net- If Process Name is like?

Tags: vb.net

Is there something like a If Processname contains "lol" then.......

I've only seen something like cls.ProcessName.Like or something like that but obviously that is not working in .net

Do you guys have any clue on how to check that? I know that there is Processname.StartsWith but that's not what I want.

Comment: `ProcessName` is just a string so any string processing function will work. You could try `Contains`. If you need something more powerful then go with a `Regex`.

Comment: [String.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension method

```
Module extensionMethods
    <Extension>
    Public Function [Like](ByVal processes As Process(), Name As String) As Process()
        Return processes.Where(Function(x) x.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains(Name.ToLower())).ToArray()
    End Function
End Module
```

Then you can call

```
 Dim processes As Process() = Process.GetProcesses().Like("lol")
```

Which will return an array of processes containing the text 'lol'

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
Dim procExists as Boolean = Process.GetProcesses().Any(Function(p) p.Name.Contains(processName)
```